# derive the trajectory by a vector with libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

[image]

Hello everyone ,
I am developing a game where two points, one is A, and the other is B , the point A is a cannon and the other is the point where there is a touch of the user.

how can I do to get the line , say infinite to proceed with the bullet starting from point A ?

My math skills are a bit scarce : /

Someone who can recommend a way to do it with libgdx / java ?

Comment: There are some videos that can be interesting for you  http://youtu.be/sKCF8A3XGxQ?list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOpdhYedlD-yCB7WQoHf-My Follow some of them you'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need the vector position of B minus the vector position of A, which will give the vector pointing from A to B. Try having a read through [this](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-introvector-2009-1.pdf), a basic knowledge of vectors is indispensible if you are going to be making games

Answer (score 0):

To represent state, you can use something like following.

```
public class Bullet extends Actor {
    private Vector2 position;
    private Vector2 velocity;

    public Bullet(Vector2 position, Vector2 velocity) {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        // Since newPosition = oldPosition + velocity * time elapsed
        this.position.mulAdd(this.velocity, delta / 1000);
    }

    // Override draw method to handle rendering.
}
```

Now, you can initialize a new `Bullet` at each touch event (or whenever you wish)

```
Bullet createBullet(Vector2 canonPosition, Vector2 touchPosition) {
    return new Bullet(canonPosition.cpy(), //Initial position of bullet.
                      touchPosition.sub(canonPosition).nor()); // Velocity
}
```

Now just add the `Bullet` to the stage and have fun.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.